# Exclude a method from app.all function fastify

Tags: fastify

I am using Fastify for a simple API. However, I am having some issues with @fastify/cors.

I have a router that uses `app.all()` method, however, when I install cors it errors with this message:

```
Error: Method 'OPTIONS' already declared for route '*' with constraints '{}'
```

I have determined the error to be that I am using `app.all()` however I need to use this for how my API works. Is there a way to call all HTTP methods except OPTIONS on `app.all()` or a similar function that would not use the OPTIONS method?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `fastify.route` call, the `method` option supports a list of methods where you can specify whichever ones you want. You can read about this in the `fastify.route` [docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#routes-options).

> `method`: currently it supports `'DELETE'`, `'GET'`, `'HEAD'`, `'PATCH'`, `'POST'`, `'PUT'`, `'OPTIONS'`, `'SEARCH'`, `'TRACE'`, `'PROPFIND'`, `'PROPPATCH'`, `'MKCOL'`, `'COPY'`, `'MOVE'`, `'LOCK'` and `'UNLOCK'`. It could also be an array of methods.